# Extracting data from JSON field in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract some data from a JSON field in Redshift.

Given below is a sample view of the data I am working with.

```
{"fileFormat":"excel","data":{"name":John,"age":24,"dateofbirth":1993,"Class":"Computer Science"}}
```

I am able to extract data for the first level namely data corresponding to 
`fileFormat` and `data` as below:

```
select CONFIGURATION::JSON -> 'fileFormat' from table_name;
```

I am trying to extract information under `data` like `name`, `age`,`dateofbirth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Redshift's native function `json_extract_path_text`
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

```
SELECT
  json_extract_path_text(
    configuration,
      'data',
      'name'
  )
    AS name,
  json_extract_path_text(
    configuration,
      'data',
      'age'
  )
    AS age,
  etc
FROM
  yourTable
```

Comment: @scottmartin - You're welcome, feel free to upvote and accept answers that help you ;)

Comment: will do. It's asking me to wait for 10 more minutes to accept the answer..